Could users with <10k reputation be able to see the content of deleted SG questions that they've taken a review action on?
A long time ago, a change was made to allow users without the 10k tools the ability to see the content of questions/answers they've reviewed. From that post, the rationale was:

Displaying the post within the context of the review item when you participated in the review and are given a link to it seems reasonable.
...
This request strikes me as reasonable as it would only expose deleted information in cases where the viewer had already seen it.

This has been maintained for awhile now. I frequently use this ability to double-back on reviews I've made in the past and see how those posts panned out following my review. It can act as a great learning tool in the event that I missed something, or it can act as some semblance of closure if a given post was self-deleted by the author. Additionally, at-a-glance, I can take a look at my review history and see which questions were deleted with the "Deleted" tag:

This ability isn't available in the Staging Ground. Links to posts I've taken a review action on that have subsequently been deleted simply yield a 404. It doesn't even include the helpful "Deleted for reasons of moderation"/"Voluntarily deleted by the post author" message.
These deleted SG posts are still visible in the Review history page, but the links just lead to 404s, and there's no indication that a given post is deleted at that page's level (to me, as a <10k user, anyway). All but two of the posts in the following screenshot are deleted:

Could we achieve parity with the existing review queues, and grant users who have taken a review action on a given post the ability to see that link even if it is deleted later?

(For reference, I did ask for this during the Beta (SO for Teams link), but it didn't receive much attention at the time)

Out of curiosity: You can also not access published posts that have been deleted by Roomba (which is a thing, beta team post here) in the SG, right (e.g. that one which I picked arbitrarily)? If you can't, do you still see the SG in the timeline of the main site post?

Correct, dan. I do still see the timeline entry in the main site post, though.
